# Kubernetes Helm Arquillian test from 2 different pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I am running two separate pods for my helm test purposes, one contains the service with its dependencies and another one is the test pod running the tests. 
Currently my arquillian tests use localhost as the address, however there is none since the service is running on the other pod. Tried playing around with ingress to setup hostname as localhost of the other pod but that seems to not work or I'm doing something incorrectly.

My question is what's the easiest way to let the 2 pods know about each other with least interference to the current arquillian tests, so I could successfully run my integration tests? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Service definition in your chart?

Comment: @Jayooo using service, pod1->service1 -> service2->pod2